# Reuse Field Names in Union Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, coding-style

Is there a way to re-use field names within a UNION query to avoid writing the field names each time?
I want to condense a query in the following example:

```
Select A, B, C, D
From Table1
Union all
Select A, B, C, D
From Table2
Union all
Select A, B, C, D
From Table3
```

Comment: Condense the query to what?  This version is quite reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Each constituent query in a union has to be able to stand alone. What you've written is the shortest possible.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you name your fields in the first query, the following queries don't care what your field names are; you don't have to alias them. SQL doesn't care. They do have to be the same data types, however.